# wordpress query posts, get all posts for current month from custom field date

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have an events custom post type in wp 3.1  I am using the following query_posts:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=event&meta_key=event_date&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC'); ?>
```

As you can see I am ordering by the custom post type date.  My issue is that I want to list only the events for the current month.  Query posts offers monthnum but then I need to pass the monthnum into the query and I have no idea how that would even be possible.  The date format is YYYY-mm-dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we were to get the date of the publication of the post it would be something like:

```
$today = getdate();
query_posts( 'year=' . $today["year"] . '&monthnum=' . $today["mon"] . '&post_type=event&meta_key=event_date&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC' );
```

But to get the date from the meta values, have you tried?:

```
query_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'event_date', 'meta_value' => '2011-02-01', 'meta_compare' => '>=', 'post_type' => 'event' ) );
```

You can get the first day of the current month with something like:

```
date( "m/d/Y", strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y') );
```

Otherwise, I would try by retrieving all the posts as you were doing and then make date objects with each meta value and compare its month and year with current.

Comment: I have looked at that documentation.  The issue is that I need to write a function that gets the current month (you've outlined that), then gets all the posts in that month, from the custom field date.  The challenge that I don;t know how to fix is getting the posts by custom field date...  Does that make sense?

Comment: I haven't realized you needed the date from a custom field. It makes sense being an "event" post type! I updated the answer with my thoughts.

Comment: so essentially I need to get the current month, put it in a variable, then compare meta_key (somehow converting the date string returned by the custom field to month) and the variable containing the current month???